# Why can't I send model? Spring Boot 2 - Thymealf

Tags: java, spring-boot, web, thymeleaf

I can not open the registration page. If I delete the th:field page is displayed. How can I solve problem. I can not speak English well Thank you...

**Error**

```
 Whitelabel Error Page
    This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
    Thu Mar 01 01:10:34 EET 2018
    There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
    An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/register.html]")
```

**Exception**

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/register.html]")
```

**Register HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>Register</h3>
<form th:action="@{register}" method="post" th:object="${user}">

<input type="text"  th:field="*{username}">
<input type="text"  th:field="*{password}">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
 </body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value="", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHomePage()
    {
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="register",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getRegisterPage(Model model)
    {
        model.addAttribute("user",new User());
        return "register";
    }

}
```

Comment: Try `th:action="@{/register}"` instead of `th:action="@{register}"` (notice the added forward slash)

Comment: @FlorianCramer I tried but it was not working. thanks for comment

Answer (score 0):

Close all your input tags and try `th:action="@{/register}"`.

Comment: change -> return "register"; to -> return "/register"; in getRegisterPage

Answer (score 0):

I was using lombok in my application and i was get this error. To resolve this issue, make sure you have the correct getter and setter methods for the  property field in your User class. Declare the getter and setter method explicitly in your user class and try...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).